# MATLAB: How to alter the output of ode45 before each and every iteration?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

This is my integration function:

```
function dy_dt=myode(t,y)
dy_dt=(-2*y+3);
```

This is my main script:

```
time_period=[0 10];
IC=[21,12];
[t,y]=ode45(@myode,0:0.1:10,IC);
```

This program runs fine. The first initial condition I have given.

**(NOTE: I have a reference set of y values(yref) as an array)**

At the end of first iteration, a `y` value is created. In the beginning, `y(1)=yref(1)`. In the next iteration, I want check the error between `y(2)`and `yref(2)`. Likewise for every iteration, this has to be done. How can I do this?

Comment: I assume that your integration function is just an example as it has a closed form solution that obviates the need for numerical integration. Why do you need to do this at the end of every iteration instead of performing the whole integration over `time_period` and then checking your error afterwards? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually I have a code for a non linear system.. It is a model for a particle to move in a curved path.. I have a set of differential equations as a model for that... Inputs - velocity , angle of projection...As a result of that code i get the coordinates of its path..(But i have a reference path as a set of coordinates).. i need to match that reference path..for that i need to find the error at every instant...** in my question  I was actually trying to give a similar example**

Comment: You can use `outputFcn` which calls a function you specify after every integration step. Look up the documentation for `odeset`. I can't give an answer to your specific question because I don't really understand it.